# Final fields Vs. Volatile

Tags: java, final

From the `java` docs of final `field` semantics:

[Final field in JDK14](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)

They are guaranteeing to see the `final` field as set in `constructor`, please find the code below:

```
class FinalFieldExample { 
    final int x;
    int y; 
    static FinalFieldExample f;

    public FinalFieldExample() {
        x = 3; 
        y = 4; 
    } 

    static void writer() {
        f = new FinalFieldExample();
    } 

    static void reader() {
        if (f != null) {
            int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
            int j = f.y;  // could see 0
        } 
    } 
}
```

Now here I am confused about `volatile` vs `final` .

To my understanding `final` filed is used make sure you can not change the variable in application and `volatile` guarantees to maintain the order and avoid happen before relationship.

So my question is how come they guarantee the visibility and ordering using `final` variable instead of `volatile` ? Please help.

Comment: `volatile` is about visibility mainly. And I don't understand your question .. could you rephrase it?

Comment: Done , please check now.

Comment: `final` doesn't garantee ordering. It does garantee visibility because when a field is `final` it won't be changed anymore. It won't matter if a thread caches the value, the value will stay the same for all threads. In terms of visibility: Every thread *sees* the same thing.

Comment: So does this mean final variables will not be part of CPU cache and they are directly written on memory - thus making sure all thread of different CPU cores will see the latest value always.

Comment: Nono, `final` has nothing to do with caching per se. It garantees *visibility* because when the field is initialized, it won't change anymore. This is what `final` means. Every thread that uses the field initially won't ever see a different value. It will always be the same, logically. Threads can cache the value in CPU register, or local cache or whatever, this won't affect the program negatively, because the value will always be the same. There won't be a need for synchronization. The *visibility* of the value is always garanteed.

Comment: The semantics of final and volatile have not changed between Java 8 and Java 14. Why do you think they have?

Comment: Since you didn't reply to me, and your question does not seem to apply exclusively to Java 14, I have edited that out of the question.

Comment: Thanks Michael . Actually question was not related to semantics it is related to a example that is mentioned in Java 14 specs. So I tagged it as java 14.

Comment: @akuzminykh - Please check the answer below , I am looking for this , thanks for putting your efforts .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is how come they guarantee the visibility and ordering using final variable

Because they defined it that way, and it's now the job of the VM to adhere to this definition.

Of course, the follow-up question is: Why did they define it that way?

It's because of a weird "feature" of the Java memory model. Consider this example

```
class Foo {
    int x;
    volatile int y;
    Foo() {
        x = 3;
        y = 4;
    }

    static final Foo INSTANCE;
    static {
       INSTANCE= new Foo();
    }
}
```

The static intitializer will be compiled into this (simplified pseudocode):

```
   Foo tmp = allocate(Foo.class)
   Foo.INSTANCE = tmp
   tmp.x = 3
   tmp.y = 4
```

As you can see, the instance is made public before the constructor is executed, `volatile` doesn't change anything here.

This behavior is unexpected for most developer and can lead to very hard-to-debug bugs. Thus, to reduce the extend of this issue a bit, the specification was adjusted to require final fields to be initialized before the instance is made public.

Example from above, with `x` declared `final`.

```
   Foo tmp = allocate(Foo.class)
   tmp.x = 3
   Foo.INSTANCE = tmp
   tmp.y = 4
```

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion _The static intitializer will be compiled into this_?

Comment: @Savior http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html, see "A test case showing that it doesn't work"

Comment: That's a very outdated article. In any case, I might agree if the example in your question reflected the one in the OP. But you're doing the instantiation within a `static` block that performs its own synchronization. No other thread can see `INSTANCE` until the initializer has completed.

Comment: I haven't to date seen anything that might suggest this article is outdated in any way whatsoever. If you know more about this, please share.

Comment: I shouldn't have said outdated. I just meant dated and unofficial. Can you please quote something more official (like the JLS) and address the rest of my previous comment. Your claim about the order of things is false for the sample code you started with.

Comment: "quote something more official" Have you seen the "signed by" part? It doesn't get more official than that. The JLS doesn't explicitly define this, but it doesn't forbid it either. It's a deliberate loophole to allow optimizations. So best I can do is link the entire JLS and say "you won't find anything contradicting this". Regarding my code example, yes there is another layer of synchronization around class loading which might make it more difficult to observe this behavior in this particular example. If it makes you happy I can replace it with the writer/reader code from the official example

Comment: Yes, please do.